# read hdf file from google cloud storage using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage, hdf5, hdf

Greetings Coders and Google cloud developers and professionals.
Am trying to read a list of hdf files from google cloud storage with the built in method "pd.read_hdf()" provided by pandas where file name is like that ("client1.h").
My problem is that i always get this error :

```
NotImplementedError: Support for generic buffers has not been implemented.
```

after deep searching in different forums and sites i realized that many have encountered the same problem but there is no solution provided.

the code i have used is below:

```
from google.cloud.storage import blob, bucket
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('file___.json') 

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')

blob = bucket.blob("data1.h")

df = pd.read_hdf(blob, mode='r+')

print(df)
```

i tried as well with code below and i got the same error:

```
 blob = bucket.blob("data1.h")
 data = download_as_string() #as_bytes as_text
 df = pd.read_hdf(io.BytesIO(data), mode='r+')
```

When i download the file to my local environment and i read it using its path , it works well and there is no problem but unfortunately in cloud storage i have a huge amount of files so i can't download all of them to work with.

!!! please !! anyone have a solution or a suggestion , i ask him to share it.

Answer (score 1):

The feature doesn't seem to be implemented yet.

As you mentioned, downloading the file to your local file system first will let you use `read_hdf()`. This is a working workaround.

For`read_hdf()` to work, one needs to pass a string that `os.path.exists(path_or_buf)` will result in True. You may want to help pandas developers implementing the feature. If that is the case, [see the current implementation here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/io/pytables.py#L382-L395).

The issue you are passing through is already opened in the issues section of pandas GitHub repo, however users are only mentioning that the problem happens with data in S3 ([see here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31902)). You may want to share your problem in that issue or open a new one as well. To open a new issue, [go here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).